How to automate the startup configuration for different cases by one click?
We have many projects in our solution. Some projects work together in different cases. We use the 'Startup Project'-window to configure the projects to start:

When we switch from test-case A to test-case B (or any other cases), then we need to disable projects which are not needed and enable projects, which are required for test-case B. Therefore we switch the Actions 'None' and 'Start' every time manually. This is annoying. Is there a way to automate the startup configuration for each case by one click?

Have you tried any extensions?
